# Partial derivation of a population kinetic's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, partial-derivative

In reviewing my biophysics' course on population kinetics I am stuck in finding which equation was actually used to derive from. It uses an example to "explain" the analytical method, in order to apply it on two exercises. So, my problem and question is analytically related, to which no one at other sites for biology, physics or even math have been able to help me.

The example is about a model of hares ($N_{H}$) and lynxes ($N_{L}$) (predator prey) and involving the impact of human hunting on either two.

The course claims to use several equations to derive the impact of little distortions ($\Delta N_{H}$ and $\Delta N_{L}$) on an equilibrium situation.

$\frac{d(\Delta N_{H})}{dt}=-\frac{k_{HL}k_{L,dth}}{k_{LH}}\Delta N_{L}$

$\frac{d(\Delta N_{L})}{dt}=\frac{k_{LH}k_{H}}{k_{HL}}\Delta N_{H}$

It is these resulting equations I'm mindboggled about regarding how she ever got to them. The k's are rates. I'll explain what they are a little more down this post.

The course claims to have used the following theoretical derivations:

$\frac{d(\Delta N_{H})}{dt}=(\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial N_{H}})_{dth} \Delta N_{H} + (\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial N_{L}})_{dth} \Delta N_{L}$

$\frac{d(\Delta N_{L})}{dt}=(\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial N_{H}})_{dth} \Delta N_{H} + (\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial N_{L}})_{dth} \Delta N_{L}$

with $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ being

$\frac{dN_{H}}{dt}=f_{1}(N_{H},N_{L})= k_{H}N_{H}-k_{HL}N_{L}N_{H}$

$\frac{dN_{L}}{dt}=f_{2}(N_{H},N_{L})= k_{LH}N_{H}N_{L}-k_{L,dth}N_{L}$

The first term in both equations result in the number of hares, respectively lynxes born every year, and the second term term the number of animals dying.

At equilibrium the last two equations become $0$ and thus

$N_{H,dth}=\frac{k_{L,dth}}{k_{LH}}$

$N_{L,dth}=\frac{k_{H}}{k_{HL}}$

When I partially derive $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ and plug in the equilibrium values I get

$\frac{d(\Delta N_{H})}{dt}=(k_{H}-k_{HL} N_{L})\Delta N_{H} - (k_{HL}N_{H}) \Delta N_{L}$

$=(k_{H}-\frac{k_{HL}k_{H}}{k_{HL}})\Delta N_{H} - \frac{k_{HL}k_{L,dth}}{k_{LH}} \Delta N_{L}$

$=(k_{H}-k_{H})\Delta N_{H} - \frac{k_{HL}k_{L,dth}}{k_{LH}} \Delta N_{L}$

When I compare this with the result I'm supposed to get, I'm supposed to drop the whole first term, which is possible since the first term $=0$

For the second function it is

$\frac{d(\Delta N_{L})}{dt}=(k_{LH} N_{L})\Delta N_{H} - k_{L,dth} \Delta N_{L}$

$=(\frac{k_{LH} k_{H}}{k_{HL}})\Delta N_{H} - k_{L,dth} \Delta N_{L}$

Again comparing my result I have with what I'm supposed to get, I'm supposed to drop a term, the second one this time. But this time I don't understand why.

Please, can someone explain this to me?

ETA the meaning of the k's and N's.
$N_H$:number of hares
$N_L$:number of lynxes
$k_{H}$:rate of births of hares a year per hare
$k_{HL}$: rate of hares taken per lynx per year
$k_{LR}$: rate of births of lynxes per year per lynx
$k_{L,dth}$: rate of lynxes dying per year

Comment: Notation makes it impossible (for the outsider) to unveil the mathematical problem behind it, as there might be "biological" reasons for "dropping the term". What do you mean by you are supposed to do it? is this mentioned in your lecture notes or whatever? btw @AlexR: I had good reason to delete the laplace equation tag, as it has obviously nothing to do with it.

Comment: @BlindSchleiche You are, however, not supposed to change the syntactical meaning of the post ("I do not undestand why")... Please only make tagging changes and fix layout / typography errors. Do not alter the posts content in a syntactical way.

Comment: $k_{L,dth}$ is a rate of either 0.2/year without humans hunting lynxes, or 0.4/year with humans hunting lynxes.

Comment: @AlexR: it is very strange, I actually did not change anything apart from the tags.

Comment: I altered the content of my post, because I figured out myself that the first term became zero.

Comment: @sweetsunray: yeah that's what I meant, this is "insider information".

Comment: And yes, the course mentions the actual resulting equation (the first two in my post). But in order to make an exercise on measles I needed to find the steps that lead to the actual result, and as long as I don't understand what's going on in the hare, lynx example analytically, I can't do the measles example. It's important because the partial derivations are used to check and set up a general solution regarding the oscillation of the process.

Comment: @BlindSchleiche. I did mention all the k's were rates in the post. The exact number of the rate shouldn't matter to figure out a derivation.

Comment: @sweetsunray: I think this is a misunderstanding, I was referring to relations which govern all these $k's$ and $N's$ and all that, like $N_L=k_H/k_{HL}$ (how would anyone reading the post even know why this is true?). I mean you mention it, but using an additional subscript whose meaning you don't mention, this makes it just confusing. Measles or whatever, it could even be gummy bears, mathematically they are all the same.

Comment: @Blindschleiche Equilibrium means "no change", and thus that $\frac{dN_{H}}{dt}=0$ and $\frac{dN_{L}}{dt}=0$. So, $k_{H}N_{H}−k_{HL}N_{L}N_{H}=0$ and $k_{LH}N_{H}N_{L}−k_{L,dth}N_{L}=0$. And thus $k_{H}N_{H}=k_{HL}N_{L}N_{H}$  and $k_{LH}N_{H}N_{L}=k_{L,dth}N_{L}$. And thus after elimination $k_{H}=k_{HL}N_{L}$ and $k_{LH}N_{H}=k_{L,dth}$. To finally have $\frac{k_{H}}{k_{HL}}=N_{L}$ and $N_{H}=\frac{k_{L,dth}}{k_{LH}}$. Most basic calculus, not some superior insider knowledge.

Comment: @BlindSchleiche (user removed?) it seems like the SE system failed to detect concurrent edits, as has been pointed out. I added appropriate tags to reflect your edit.

Comment: As for the criticism on the biological symbolism. Mathematically it doesn't change a thing. I could have used hearts, diamonds, or any other symbol. Mathematically it shouldn't matter. Partial derivations of biological constants and variables still remain partial derivations and follow the mathematical rules of partial derivations. Laws of biophysics, biology, physics all have to follow mathematical rules.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed my professor about it, and it turns out I made a mistake in my partial derivation of f2 $\frac{dN_{L}}{dt}=k_{LH}N_{H}N_{L}−k_{L,dth}N_{L}$

It ought to have been

$\frac{d(ΔN_{L})}{dt}=(k_{LH}N_{L})ΔN_{H}+(k_{LH}N_{H}−k_{L,dth})ΔN_{L}$

Substituting the equilibrium equations for $N_{L}$ and $N_{H}$ it becomes

$=(\frac{k_{LH}k_{H}}{k_{HL}})ΔN_{H}+(k_{LH}\frac{k_{L,dth}}{k_{LH}}-k_{L,dth})ΔN_{L}$

$=(\frac{k_{LH}k_{H}}{k_{HL}})ΔN_{H}+ 0 ΔN_{L}$

$=(\frac{k_{LH}k_{H}}{k_{HL}})ΔN_{H}$

I forgot to partially derive the first term of f2 for $N_{L}$